# How to change media files owner on hosting?

Tags: wordpress, web, web-hosting

After I upload files with wordpress default media manager, they owned by web server's process user. I have no access to shell on hosting server. How to change files owner while uploading files this way?

Comment: It's typically www-data is owner of the files uploaded and this also ensures that wordpress has the correct permission to properly interact to those files. Is there particular reason you would like that change?

Comment: Anthony, I don't know password of www-data, And owner of all my web directory is not www-data, it's ftp my user. So I want to upload files with wordpress gallery tool as my ftp user.

Comment: Have you tried asking your hosting to help you with this already?

Comment: If you don't have a terminal/shell access and I'm assuming that you are ftp-ing into the host, can you right click on a file and change permission? Like @cabrerahector have said, ask your hosting provider for shell access.